# Installing Ubuntu Web Server: error updating initramfs configuration

Tags: boot, server

I have two drives:

1. For Windows
2. Install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server

Trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Web Server on a blank second drive (size 1TB).

Trying to install on a new drive.  As Ubuntu is being installed,

**I am getting message:**
updating initramfs configuration
subiquity/error/install_fall/add_info

I am asking to reinstall or Reboot Now

If I reboot Now, I just get to localhost login.
I can get Ubuntu desktop to download and work. Just not Ubuntu Server.

Thanks